# iOS on resume not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I need a view in my app to refresh everytime the app comes back to the foreground. The code below is working perfectly with Android but nothing happens on iOS.

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {
    if($state.current.name == "app.listar_aprovacoes"){
      // code to refresh scope and view.
    };
  });
```

I also tried the following and it also doesn't work with iOS:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
       var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Foo',
        template: 'Bar'
      });
    }, false);
```

So could you help me out with a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: For some reason, updating the platform using ionic platform update ios didn't update the code for this. I removed the platform and added it again and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, updating the platform using ionic platform update ios didn't update the code for this. I removed the platform and added it again and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.addEventListener('resume', callback);` as well.

Also make sure you have the Cordova Device Plugin.
You can install it by using:

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

Generally, with the plugin installed, the first (`$ionicPlatform.on('resume', ...)`) method should work. I tested both on iOS and Android.

Comment: The [cordova events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) do not depend on `cordova-plugin-device` plugin.